# jQueryUIautocomplete not working

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to use jqueryUI autocomplete feature where the available tags will be fetched from the backend source.
Here is my code.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="span4 pull-right" id="search">
    Search : <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

**js code**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/dashboard/search"
    });
});
</script>
```

** django views.py**

```
def search(request):
    availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang"];
    ctx = {"availableTags":availableTags}
    return HttpResponse(availableTags) #returns the set of values(checked with firebug while debugging) but autocomplete doesnot works.

    #return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard.html', ctx) // returns nothing.
```

**dashboard urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('modules.energy.dashboard.views',
    url(r'^$','dashboard',name='cilantro_dashboard'),
    url(r'search','search',name='cilantro_search'),
)
```

**main urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^dashboard/', include('modules.energy.dashboard.urls')),
)
```

Here is what I receive in response while debugging with firebug.

`ActionScriptAppleScriptAspBASICCC++ClojureCOBOLColdFusionErlang`

My `availabletags` are returned but autocomplete still not works.  Where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to convert the data dict to JSON before sending it.

```
from django.utils import simplejson
data = simplejson.dumps(availableTags)
return HttpResponse(data)
```

Comment: Thanks. i got it right, but I didnt understood it. I mean my `availableTags` is a set. how can it be dumped as json?  Kindly explain. Thanks

Comment: Plus it provides the list of autocomplete, but it does not filters the result as i keep typing in. Why is it like this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're asking. My code shows how to dump as json.

Comment: I'm asking that filtration of Tags does not works. Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see and if your returned results are right, that may simply be because you are returning the autocomplete in your `div`, and not in your `input`.

Comment: Can you check your returned data? The fomatting should be `["data1","data2","data3",...]`. I prefer to use php `echo`s in my javascript, but have to prepare them this way first.

Comment: I'm not a php guy. Please tell me how should I check it? PS: As already mentioned, the response that I get is `ActionScriptAppleScriptAspBASICCC++ClojureCOBOLColdFusionErlang`. Dont know why, but it should actually return like the format you mentioned.

Comment: You should actually see the response in Firebug. Could you post it? If what you posted is your actual reponse, it sure won't work.

Comment: Yes That's the response that I'm getting.(In firebug). Where i'm getting wrong?

Comment: OK, just try this in your django views.py: `availableTags = '["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang"]';` and let me know how it goes.